# Programming Arduino Pro mini 328 with Arduino Uno SMD

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, isp, arduino-uno-smd

I apologize in advance, because there is a lot of tutorials out there about programming arduinos with another arduino, however I can't find really simple one I could understand.

I have Arduino Uno SMD version and Arduino Pro mini 328. I want to upload sketch to Arduino Pro mini using Arduino Uno in ISP mode (I guess).

I want to know EXACTLY which pins need to be connected and if all I need is Arduino IDE to upload my sketch to Pro mini ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For  upload sketch to Arduino Pro mini, unless your code size is really big and run out of space, many people use FTDI style USB to serial board (6 finger nails sized) to download via bootloader. There are tons of tutorial with good diagram. Try search by these keyword. Sparkfun and arduino.cc should have needed info for you

Comment: @JohnWilliams Thanks for comment. However, I don't want to buy another board. I just want to use my 2 existing ones.

Comment: How exactly have existing guides and tutorials failed you?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Well, I haven't actually found any which would cover exactly my scenario - meaning Arduino Uno SMD and Pro mini 328.

Comment: ISP via the Arduino is still done the same way regardless.

Comment: You should be able to take the Uno-as-target instructions and use them with the mini simply by connecting to the same (Arduino) pin names - digital 10 through 13 and RST (reset).

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ok, but what bothers me are advices about removing Atmel chip from its socket in Arduino Uno. But I have SMD version, so it's not possible. This really confuses me.

Comment: The ISP instructions do not involve doing that.  You might be thinking of instructions for using an Arduino with it's main processor removed as a USB-serial interface to talk to the bootloader of one without its own USB interface; but you said you wanted to use ISP programming rather than bootloader programming.

Comment: OK and could you point me to some comprehensive tutorial ? I am looking at http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP but it's not about Arduino Pro mini - I don't know if there is something special involved or I can wire it as in first diagram. This tutorial talks about burning bootloader, but I want to upload my sketch, I am really confused here.

Comment: @Frodik, two different things. ISP programming is used to program the boot loader, which is a small program that runs on startup and allows for larger programs to be uploaded using serial. You need a USB to serial converter. It has a USB port and a female header that connect to the 6 pins on the arduino pro.

Comment: @geometrikal I apology for my confusion. Now your comment makes sense. So please, what do I do if I want to just upload my sketch ? I am pretty sure that my Pro mini already has Arduino bootloader.

Comment: You use the same setup you would as for burning a bootloader, only in the software you select something like upload using programmer and select arduino as ISP as the programmer.  Long term you are going to want that logic-level USB serial cable anyway, as it enables you to get debug output from your sketch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this tutorial:

> http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Examples-2-Use-an-Arduino-as-a-FTDI-Progr/

Works fine for me (I have a redboard, also with SMD microcontroller). In short this is the pinMap:

```
UNO BOARD (SMD)    Pro Mini 5V
       GND             GND
       5V              VCC
       RX              RX1
       TX              TX1
       Reset           GRN
```

Comment: Just to be sure, RX and TX on Uno board are digital pins 1 and 2, right ? But that would mean, that if I wanted to upload sketch to finished project which would have soldered all the digital pins to other modules, I couldn't use those 2 pins (RX,TX). That was the reason why I wanted to use ISP so I wouldn't have to sacrifice 2 pins.

Comment: @Frodik - ISP requires 3 pins plus reset, bootloader requires 2 plus reset.  That doesn't mean you have to reserve the pins, but it does mean you can't use them for things which conflict.  For example, you can use them as outputs from the ATmega to peripherals, as long as spurious operation of the peripherals during programming is not problematic.  But you shouldn't use them to read from peripherals which might problematically drive signals onto those pins during the programming.

Comment: @ChrisStratton But if I understand it correctly, ISP requires different pins than digital 1-13, right ?

Comment: @Frodik As Chris mentioned, 3 pins are used, these pins are D11, D12, D13. The arduino website shows this http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP. Remember that a Pro Mini is literally an Uno that got shrunk.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this tutorial if you want to upload sketches to Pro mini with Arduino UNO with SDM chip 
http://www.instructables.com/id/Uploading-sketches-to-Pro-Mini-using-Arduino-UNO-b

Comment: It is preferable to answer questions directly rather than simply linking to external sites. Adding a summary of the Instructable text, specifically address the question asked by the OP about which pins are involved, would go a long way to helping the the OP, other people with the same problem, and getting your answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Following the tutorial on http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Examples-2-Use-an-Arduino-as-a-FTDI-Progr/ I was able to upload the blink sketch to the Pro Mini 5V version with an Arduino Nano. After I tried uploading the sketch that I really wanted to use but got many errors in the IDE I tried a couple more with no luck. I had stumble on another article earlier about using the Arduino Nano to program the Pro Mini http://www.electronicsmayhem.com/?p=31. I had tried that method but with no luck but using the first tutorial & only changing one thing from it with info from the article i mentioned I was able to upload the sketch without any errors. The only thing I changed was I didn't connect the TX from the Nano to the TXI of the Mini.

```
   Arduino Nano     Pro Mini 5V
       GND-------------GND
       5V--------------VCC
       RX--------------RX1
       Reset-----------GRN(DTR)
```